# How to post information in CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

The following is the html I wanna tackle with.

[image]

I wanna post a query and see the weather reports for that city. I tried my codes:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var utils = require('utils');

casper.start('http://www.weather.com.cn/weather1d/101210101.shtml'); 
casper.waitForSelector('input', function()
{
    this.fillXPath('div.search clearfix',{'//input[@id="txtZip"]':'shijiazhuang'},true);
}); 
casper.then(function()
{   
    utils.dump(this.getTitle());
}); 
casper.run();
```

It did not print the web paeg title on the console. I also tried this:

```
casper.waitForSelector('input', function()
{
    this.fillSelectors('div.search clearfix',{'input[id="txtZip"]':'shijiazhuang'},true);
}); 
}
);
```

I did not get any web page title also. I got quite confused and did not what I had done wrong. Besides, it seems that *this.fill* method only tackles with name attributes to post information on CasperJS's official website. I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CasperJS script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create(), utils = require('utils');
    casper

.start('http://www.weather.com.cn/weather1d/101210101.shtml',function(){
    this
         .wait(3000,function(){
    this.capture('search.png');
    utils.dump(this.getTitle());
})
         .evaluate(function(){
            document.getElementById('txtZip').value='shijiazhuang';
            document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').click();
       })
})
    .run();
```

Result:

"【石家庄天气】石家庄今天天气预报,今天,今天天气,7天,15天天气预报,天气预报一周,天气预报15天查询"

[search.png](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBneW03N1IyNGNvT28)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correct, you only have to modify your script a little bit. 
Just modify the selector of the input field the actual don't seems to work, then you should get the correct result. 
"this.fillXPath" only fills up the form and don't post it.

```
...
// fill the form
casper.waitForSelector('input', function() {
    this.fillXPath('#txtZip', {
        '//input[@id="txtZip"]': 'shijiazhuang'
    }, true);
});
// trigger - post the form
casper.then(function() {
    this.click('#btnZip');
});
// i can't speak chinese - wait for some specific change on this page
casper.wait(5000);
// take a screenshot of it
casper.then(function() {
    this.capture("shijiazhuang_weather.png");
});
...
```